# How to definitely fix this error: .NET Framework execution was aborted by escalation policy because of out of memory?

Tags: sql-server, memory, out-of-memory, .net-assembly

First of all, here is our setup:

- SQL Server 2014 SP2 Standard Edition 64-bit
- 128GB of RAM (maximum allowed by Standard Edition), of which 120GB is allocated to SQL Server
- The server currently hosts ~5000 databases which are all similar (same tables, stored proc, etc.) for a total of 690GB of data (mdf files only)

Now what happens:

Every now and then, after the server has been up for some time, we receive this error when executing queries on some databases:

```
.NET Framework execution was aborted by escalation policy because of out of memory
```

This error happens more often when we perform an update of all client databases (when we launch a feature) using [Red Gate SQL Multi Script](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dba/sql-multi-script/). Of the ~5000 DBS, we have the error on 70 of them. Running the update script again, the error happens on a portion, and so on until we have all databases updated correctly. This is just annoying.

We have this error since a long time. Our server had 64GB of RAM, so we just added more memory to max out SQL Server Standard Editor, but still, the error came back a few days later. We think the error might be a symptom of something else.

A few things that might help to get an answer:

- Our version of SQL Server is 64-bit, so we think we don't have to deal with [Virtual Address Space Reservation](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jonathan_kehayias/archive/2009/07/07/understanding-the-vas-reservation-aka-memtoleave-in-sql-server.aspx)
- The error also happens when running from a client app written in PHP/Linux, so we're not talking about .NET framework of the client code
- In our databases, the only usage of .NET framework we make is [GROUP_CONCAT](http://groupconcat.codeplex.com/), a.NET CLR Assembly with User Defined Functions which help us simulate MySQL GROUP_CONCAT aggregate. We have a copy of the assembly in each of our 5000 client databases.
- We already tried to lower the  `max server memory` setting (to 96GB), but we were still getting those errors

If more info is needed I will update my question.

Comment: I think there are not enough memory for CLR. Here is good article, hope it helps: https://www.johnsansom.com/sql-server-memory-configuration-determining-memtoleave-settings/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been 4 months since I tried a fix, and I did not experienced the bug again. Still, I don't have the exact explanation for the bug, but here is what I tried and it seems to work:

My guess was that having the same .NET CLR Assembly in each of our 5000+ databases might be the problem and increased memory usage for .NET in some way.

1. I created a new database named something like `DotNetClrUtils`
2. I copied the .NET CLR Assembly for `GROUP_CONCAT` in this database
3. I changed all usage of `GROUP_CONCAT` in all our client code and stored procedures to reference the single instance in `DotNetClrUtils` database (calling it like this: `DotNetClrUtils.dbo.GROUP_CONCAT_D(col, ',')`)

That's all, and now this problem is gone!